# React not rendering images

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from '../ButtonElements';
import ImageOne from './svg-1.svg';

    import { InfoContainer,
            InfoWrapper,
            InfoRow,
            Column1,
            TextWrapper,
            TopLine,
            Heading,
            SubTitle,
            BtnWrap,
            Column2,
            ImgWrap,
            Img} from "./infoElements";

const InfoSection = ({lightBg,id,imgStart,topLine,headLine,darkText,description,buttonLabel,img,alt}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <InfoContainer lightBg= {lightBg} id={id} >
                <InfoWrapper>
                    <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart} >
                        <Column1>
                            <TextWrapper>
                                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                                <Heading> {headLine} </Heading>
                                <SubTitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</SubTitle>
                                <BtnWrap>
                                    <Button to='home'>{buttonLabel}</Button>
                                </BtnWrap>
                            </TextWrapper>
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <ImgWrap>
                                <Img alt={alt} src={ImageOne} />
                            </ImgWrap>
                        </Column2>
                    </InfoRow>
                </InfoWrapper>
            </InfoContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default InfoSection
```

and please mind that these are custom tags. Plus I even tried creating an object and storing files link in a property and passing that property into the tag but it also does not work. Any help would be appreciated!

This the code where I have described ImgWrapper and Img

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const InfoContainer = styled.div`
    color: #fff;
    background: ${({lightBg})=>(lightBg ? '#f9f9f9' : '#010606' )};

    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }
`

export const InfoWrapper = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 860px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0 24px;
    justify-content: center;
`
export const InfoRow = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-areas: 
        ${({imgStart})=> (imgStart ? `'col2 col1'` : `'col1 col2'` )};
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        grid-template-areas:
            ${({imgStart})=> (imgStart ? `'col1' 'col2' ` : 
            ` 'col1 col1' 'col2 col2' `)};
    }
`

export const Column1 = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    grid-area: col1
`

export const Column2 = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    grid-area: col2
`

export const TextWrapper = styled.div`
    max-width: 540px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
`

export const TopLine = styled.p`
    color: #01bf71;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
`

export const Heading = styled.h1`
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: ${({lightText})=> ( lightText ? '#f7f8fa' : '#010606' )};

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
`

export const SubTitle = styled.p`
    max-width: 440px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: ${({darkText})=>(darkText ? '#010606' : '#ffffff')};
`

export const BtnWrap = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
`

export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
    max-width: 555px;
    height: 100%;
`

export const Img = styled.image`
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding-right: 0;
```

this one is for the Img and ImgWrap here Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You will have provide the code of your `ImgWrap` and `Img` components only then we will able to tell where your wrong

Comment: @GayatriDipali I have updated the thread! please check now

Comment: Try assigning height to the image

Comment: @GayatriDipali Will do! What should be the recommended size mam? I want it on left side thats why. Sorry for asking noob question just learning react right now

Comment: Just play around with the values